# Manage individual debug keystores per Project in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-drive-api, android-keystore

I started developing several new Android apps that connect to Google Drive and use the Google Drive SDK. All apps are registered with the standard and global debug keystore in the API-Console. In addition all apps are registered with their individual release keystore in the API Console. The Service "Drive API" is enabled for all apps.

I can install and run all release builds against Google Drive.

If I use the debug versions of the apps only the first app comes thru - all other apps receive a 401 (no valid credential error).

So my question is: Is it possible that a global debug keystore for more than one Android App connecting to Google Drive is not possible?

And if yes, how can I manage individual debug keystores on a project base within Eclipse?

Many thanks in advance.